# Input not working on w3schools tryit editor

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I'm new to Stack Overflow (though not Stack Exchange), so any feedback would be appreciated.

When I try to write a piece of code that includes the python `input` command on the [w3schools python tryit editor](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_default), I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./prog.py", line <line # of input>, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

For example,

```
print("foo")
x = input("bar")
```

gives the error listed above. The code works fine in Linux python 3, or programmiz, etc.

Is the error on my side or w3schools? Is it fixable? If so, how?

Comment: User  input is not available on the online environment

Comment: If you want to "fix it", just download Python and an IDE. If you can't install an IDE, run it using commands.